# ajaxStop does not function properly

Tags: ajax

I've got the following code that executes after a button click. It is supposed to get some data from an ajax call and decide whether to continue with the rest code or break. For some reason it does not work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "button#sub1" ).on("click", function(event) {
        //event.preventDefault();

        //alert("Function temporary disabled");
        //return;
        var htmlString = $( "#select-result" ).text();
        var v=$( "#select-result2" ).text();
        var s=$( "#select-result3" ).text();
        var c=$( "#select-result7" ).text();
        var cont=true;
        //alert(v);
        //alert(s);
        //alert(c);
        //alert(htmlString);
        //alert(htmlString.indexOf("none"));
        //alert(htmlString.indexOf("undefined"));
        $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "getpending.php",
                    data: { //getpending.php uses a $_SESSION variable, no need to pass any data here 
},
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        if(data)
                        {
                            alert("You have a pending submission.");
                            cont=false;
                        }
                    } 
                });
        $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        if(cont)
        {

        if(htmlString!="" && htmlString.indexOf("undefined") == -1)
        {

            //$("button#sub1").attr("disabled", true);

            $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "calculate.php",
                    data: { 'raw' : htmlString, 'pts' : v, 'stars' : s, 'cats' : c },
                    /* success: function(data)
                    {
                        alert("success!"); 
                    } */
                }); 

            $( "#select-result" ).empty();
            $( "#select-result2" ).empty();
            $( "#select-result3" ).empty();
            $( "#select-result7" ).empty();
            $( "#sel1" ).text("Submitted for approval");
            $(function() 
            {

            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#sel1").hide('fade', {}, 500)
            }, 2000);
            });
        }
        else if(htmlString=="")
            alert("You need to select at least one category to submit...");
        else if(htmlString.indexOf("undefined")>-1)
            alert("Invalid Selection...");
        }
        });
        $( "#select-result" ).empty();
        htmlString.empty();
        $( "#select-result2" ).empty();
        v.empty();
        $( "#select-result3" ).empty();
        s.empty();
        $( "#select-result7" ).empty();
        c.empty();
    });
});
</script>
```

Can you spot the reason why this is not working?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve it using the 'when' function:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "button#sub1" ).on("click", function(event) {
        //event.preventDefault();

        //alert("Function temporary disabled");
        //return;
        var htmlString = $( "#select-result" ).text();
        var v=$( "#select-result2" ).text();
        var s=$( "#select-result3" ).text();
        var c=$( "#select-result7" ).text();

        //alert(v);
        //alert(s);
        //alert(c);
        //alert(htmlString);
        //alert(htmlString.indexOf("none"));
        //alert(htmlString.indexOf("undefined"));
        var cont=true;
        function aj1() { return $.ajax({

                    type: "GET",
                    url: "getpending.php",
                    data: { },
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        if(data)
                        {
                            alert("You have a pending submission.");
                            cont=false;

                        }
                    } 
                });
            }

        $.when(aj1()).done(function() {
        if(cont) {

        if(htmlString!="" && htmlString.indexOf("undefined") == -1)
        {

            //$("button#sub1").attr("disabled", true);

            $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "calculate.php",
                    data: { 'raw' : htmlString, 'pts' : v, 'stars' : s, 'cats' : c },
                    /* success: function(data)
                    {
                        alert("success!"); 
                    } */
                }); 

            $( "#select-result" ).empty();
            $( "#select-result2" ).empty();
            $( "#select-result3" ).empty();
            $( "#select-result7" ).empty();
            $( "#sel1" ).text("Submitted for approval");
            $(function() 
            {

            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#sel1").hide('fade', {}, 500)
            }, 2000);
            });
        }

        else if(htmlString=="")
            alert("You need to select at least one category to submit...");
        else if(htmlString.indexOf("undefined")>-1)
            alert("Invalid Selection...");


        $( "#select-result" ).empty();
        htmlString.empty();
        $( "#select-result2" ).empty();
        v.empty();
        $( "#select-result3" ).empty();
        s.empty();
        $( "#select-result7" ).empty();
        c.empty();
        }
        });
    });
});
```